# The graph must be daily started

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j v3.5 Enterprise installed as a service on Windows 2016 Std server.
Works fine but we have to start the project each morning.

No timeout parameters found.
The windows service ( Neo4j Graph Database ) is running but we have to start the project in the Neo4J Desktop in order to reach the graph from the browser.

No error messages

Comment: Does the server that is running on get restarted everyday?

Comment: I don't see the link between the neo4j desktop and the neo4j server installed as a server. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: Hi FabAdmin! Welcome to SO! In order to answer your question, we need to know exactly what it is that you're asking, and there isn't actually a question here. To make sure that we don't answer the wrong thing, could you tell us what it is that you'd like to have happen?